# How to add reference to 'System.Web.Helpers

Tags: visual-studio

Update-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Web.Helpers'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -reinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand

Comment: And right-clicking on your projects "refrences" and selecting "Add reference" won't do?

Comment: what should i do after add reference

Comment: but no it doesnt work if i do it like that